# PHP/Java: How to copy the file from one folder into another folder inside the remote server

Tags: java, php, localhost, remote-server

I have a remote server where inside that there are two new folders in one folder there is mp3 files which have been stored and another folder is empty

First folder has collection of music files

```
http://localhost/Android/online/original/all/all.mp3
```

Second folder is empty

```
http://localhost/Android/online/duplicate/all/all.mp3
```

Server is same for both the path but folder is different instead of original duplicate folder has been created .

now i have to copy the music files from one path to another path using php or java

PHP CODE:

I used php copy method

```
src = http://localhost/Android/online/original/all/all.mp3
dest = http://localhost/Android/online/duplicate/all/all.mp3
copy('src','dest');
```

ERROR:

```
copy(http://localhost/Android/online/duplicate/all.mp3) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in C:\xampp\htdocs\Android\App\copy.php on line 25
```

When i code it in java using FileUtils method in eclipse i am getting java Exception as file not found exception

```
try
{
FileUtils(src,dest);
}
catch(IoException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error:

```
java exception File Not found exception
```

Can please anyone tell what needs to be corrected in this above code snippets and how to copy the mp3 file inside the same remote server

Comment: php is run on the server, so expects a folder path relative to the executing script, something like: "online/original/all/all.mp3", not a full url with `http://localhost...` Same goes for java

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the absolute/relative local path to copy files, for example in php

```
$src = "/var/www/Android/online/original/all/all.mp3";
$dest = "/var/www/Android/online/duplicate/all/all.mp3";
copy($src, $dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Sardine* library for copying remote files with java (see [copy(String sourceUrl, String destinationUrl)](https://code.google.com/p/sardine/wiki/UsageGuide#void_copy%28String_sourceUrl,_String_destinationUrl%29).